# HTTP Post request with socket proxy c#

Tags: c#, sockets, proxy, httprequest

I have to use C# Socket class to do Post request. I can successfully create the POST request required to make the post.

The problem I'm having now is, once I recive the response its coms like this

```
§♥♥ ☻☻2
```

the code:

```
public static void Post(string host,string proxyip,int proxyport,string headers)
        {
            
            try{
                string page = "";
                string c = "CONNECT "+host+":443 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: i.instagram.com:443\r\n\r\n";
                
                Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);
                IPEndPoint proxy = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(proxyip),proxyport);
                s.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;
                Console.WriteLine(IPAddress.Parse(proxyip));
                s.Connect(proxy);            
                Console.WriteLine("Connected");
                // convert to bytes
                Byte[] bytesSent  = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(c);
                s.Send(bytesSent);
                Byte[] bytesReceived = new Byte[256];
                int bytes = 0;
                bytes = s.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, 0);
                page = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes);
                
                

                if (page.Contains("HTTP/1.1 200")){
                     
                    Console.WriteLine("ok");
                    Byte[] header  = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(headers);
                    s.Send(header);
                    Byte[] HeadersReceived = new Byte[256];
                    bytes = 0;
                    bytes = s.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, 0);
                    page = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes);
                    Console.WriteLine(page);
                }else{
                    Console.WriteLine("not ok");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            
        }
```

**How i can get it right?**